# Can't run java in bashscript

Tags: java, bash, terminal

I am trying to write a bash script that simply compiles a java file then runs it

```
#!/bin/bash
read name
javac $name
$name | sed -r "s/.java//" | java
```

but instead of running the java file, it opens java.

```
Usage: java [-options] class [args...]
           (to execute a class)
   or  java [-options] -jar jarfile [args...]
           (to execute a jar file)

       blah blah blah
```

Comment: Probably because you're trying to pipe in to Java instead of running Java like the usage instructions say to. Why can't you just use java ${name/.java/} and take advantage of bash?

Comment: Is there a good reason to avoid using an IDE? to compile and run a program is just one button.

Comment: @PeterLawrey IMO yes, there are, because you might not have an IDE around, or might be trying to automate some process, or you just want to learn something new.

Comment: Upvote for something new.  However if you don't have an IDE, you should get one.  There is no good reason to do things the hard way in this day and age IMHO. If you want to automate a build, I suggest using maven or ant.

Comment: Maven/ant are total overkill if all you want to do is to easily compile and run little Java test programs or script-ish things.

Comment: Go for @nneonneo's answer below. For reference, this is how you'd do it with your approach:  `echo "$name" | sed -r "s/\.java//" | xargs java`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try substituting this:

```
#!/bin/bash
read name
javac $name
name=$(echo $name|sed -r "s/.java//")
java $name
```

Or, even better: just enter the main class without ".java":

```
#!/bin/bash
read name
javac $name.java
java $name
```

The point is, you need to pass an *argument* to the "java" command.  You can't just use a pipe from stdout.

Comment: ...? `$name=$(sed -r "s/.java//")` `-bash: foo.java=: command not found`

Comment: Maybe I am missing some arcane bash knowledge, but to the best of what I do have, you cannot assign to `$name` as `$name` will be expanded (first). You want to start with "name=" to update the contents of the `name` variable.

Comment: It's not "really arcane".  Try this: `name=Moose.java;
echo name= $name;
name=$(echo $name|sed -r "s/.java//");
echo name= $name`

Comment: @Souren - sorry for all the stupid noise and confusion you're getting.  The problem is simple: you can't use a pipe to the Java command, you need to give it an actual argument: EX: `java myprog`.  You have several good suggestions for doing this.  'Hope that helps...

Answer (score 1):

You want to do a simple substitution with Bash? Just use the built-in substitution facility.

```
java ${name/.java/}
```

No need for `sed`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
#!/bin/bash
read name
javac $name
class=`echo $name | sed -r "s/.java//"`
`java $class`
```